# Nginx Location block to Symfony path

Tags: symfony, nginx, config, nginx-location

*Daft question*

We have a symfony-app example.com
root would be `/home/example/public_html/web`

In the symfony-app we have a `location` path of `example.com/tools/`

We wanted to setup some restrictions to this `location` block in Nginx

but everything we've tried doesn't seem to map?

is it possible to do this in nginx or does it have to be done in symfony?

basic rules like

```
location ~ /tools {
  deny all;
}
```

have no effect at all on `example.com/tools`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a restriction by the ip-address - just allow the local query and for others deny, like there:

```
location ~ /tools {
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return a response too:

```
location ~ /tools {
    deny all;
    return 403;
}
```